# Python - CSV rows into multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, python-requests

I want to convert each of the rows in my csv file into lists. But the below code doesn't work , it rather converts all the columns into lists

```
def data():
import csv

f=open("mydata.csv","r")
reader=csv.reader(f)

Type=[]
BusPsngr=[]
Bus=[]
PersoVeh=[]
LoadTrks=[]



for row in reader:
    Type.append(row[0])
    BusPsngr.append(int(row[1]))
    Bus.append(int(row[2]))
    PersoVeh.append(int(row[3]))
    LoadTrks.append(int(row[4]))
```

[my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKh4L.png)

so my first lists should be List1=['Type','2000',........,'2012'] and so on for each row.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is lists from the rows as they are in the file,

```
with open("mydata.csv") as f:
  lines = list(csv.reader(f))
```

will make `lines` something like

```
[
  ["Type", "2000", ...],
  ["Bus Pass", "...."],
]
```

You could then unpack this into 5 separate lists:

```
Type, BusPsngr, Bus, PersoVeh, LoadTrks = lines[:5]
```

## EDIT

If you want to skip the first column, you can use a list comprehension to clip it out while reading the CSV:

```
with open("mydata.csv") as f:
  lines = [line[1:] for line in csv.reader(f)]
```

## EDIT 2

To read the data into a dict (just in case the lines are in a different order than you expect) and to convert the values into integers at the same time...

```
with open("mydata.csv") as f:
  data = {
    line[0]: [int(v) for v in line[1:]]
    for line
    in csv.reader(f)
  }
print(set(data.keys()))
Type = data["Type"]
BusPsngr = data["Bus Passenger"]  # or whatever...
```

Comment: What if I dont want the first element of each row to be included in the list ? Like for example the first list would look like , Type=["2000","2001",..........,"2012"]. Second list would be BusPsngr=["317205","291425",......."410941"] . How to do this?

Comment: it worked, sorry but I have one more problem -  I want all the elements in each list to be integers rather than a string .How do I convert them ?

Comment: I added another edit. I made the output a dict, though, just to make things more resilient against the original file having a different order than you'd expect.